# Update list view title using Views.asmx web service?

Tags: 2007, web-services, list-view

How can I update the View title of a SharePoint 2007 list using the views.asmx web service?
[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/views.views.updateview%28v=office.12%29.aspx) the Views.UpdateView web method takes a parameter 
**viewProperties** =

> An XML fragment that contains all the
>   view-level properties as attributes,
>   such as Editor, Hidden, ReadOnly, and
>   Title.

But what is the structure of this XML fragment? I tried supplying `<ViewProperties Title='MyCustomView' />`
but always get an SOAP exception indicating that the viewProperties has invalid value.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the XML fragment isn't really documented but there's some clue to it in [SPView.PropertiesXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.propertiesxml%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
<View Name="{7591FC7D-8304-42C7-9456-09F4241AC6F8}" 
    Type="HTML" DisplayName="View_Name" 
    Url="Lists/List_Title/File_Name.aspx" 
    BaseViewID="1" />
```

Try using PowerShell to interrogate an existing view and find out what its PropertiesXml value is.

If you still don't have any luck and have to use web services then you will just need to recreate the view. This is a common problem when using the SharePoint SOAP web services - they are lacking in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> I was successful changing view Properties with the follow xml syntax
>
> try < viewProperties>< View Title="MyCustomView" />< /viewProperties>

or in Sharepoint 2010 the title is the displayname

< viewProperties>< View DisplayName=""MyCustomView"" />< /viewProperties>"